# hive - why dropping database deletes data for external table as well

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

when I executed created the following command, it deleted all the files as well, even for external tables.

```
drop database database_name cascade;
```

is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Can you confirm external tables pointed to which location ? Unless the storage is other than HDFS you cannot control this default behaviour. Hive cleans out the default HDFS directories as soon as you drop the db. Can you point external table to some other path than default path and then try dropping the db

Answer (score 0):

does your database name is "cascade"?
if NO(I believe), simply do drop database <database_name>

Comment: you should try comments for question.